# Python class instance returning the empty line when method is called

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop, instance

Here is my code

```py
class treasureChest:
    #Private question : String
    #Private answer : Integer
    #Private points : Integer
    def __init__(self,questionP, answerP, pointsP):
        self.__question = questionP
        self.__answer = answerP
        self.__points = pointsP


    def getQuestion(self):
        return self.__question
    

    def checkAnswer(self, answer):
        return self.__answer == answer


    def getPoints(self, attempt):
        if attempt == 1:
            return self.__points
        elif attempt == 2:
            return self.__points // 2
        elif attempt == 3 or attempt == 4:
            return self.__points // 4
        else:
            return 0


arrayTreasure = [treasureChest("",bool(),0) for i in range(6)] # arrayTreasure(5) as treasureChest
def readData():
    global arrayTreasure
    filename = "TreasureChestData.txt"
    try:
        file = open(filename, "r")
        dataFetched = (file.readline()).strip()
        for i in range(len(arrayTreasure)):
            question = dataFetched
            answer = (file.readline()).strip()
            points = (file.readline()).strip()
            arrayTreasure[i].__question = question
            arrayTreasure[i].__answer = answer
            arrayTreasure[i].__points = points 
            dataFetched = (file.readline()).strip()
        file.close()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File could not be found")

readData()
print(arrayTreasure[1].getQuestion())
```

When I run an empty line is printed instead of printing value from the list of type class.

The TreasureChestData.txt file is:

```
2*2
4
10
100/10
10
15
1000*4
4000
20
125/25
5
30
3000+4000
7000
18
```

Need help with this issue.

Comment: Attribute names starting with double underscores (but not ending with them) are *private* - those names simply do not work from outside the class.  There's lots of possible solutions here - remove at least one underscore from each name, add setter methods for each one (this is not usually considered Pythonic), put the file-reading code into a method of the class so that it has access to the names, etcc.

Comment: @jasonharper that is just a convention, and you can set value for these variable on a class instance

Comment: before setting question, anser point, see if you are getting those value or not

Comment: @sahasrara62: No, it's single underscores that are just a convention for indicating that the name should not be accessed externally.  Double leading underscores actually modify the name being used depending on the class containing the access, so you'd have to purposely use the modified name to access them elsewhere.

Comment: @jasonharper I've just tested and double underscores are a convention too. there is no such thing as private variable in python (as explained [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/private-variables-python/))

Comment: @jasonharper nope, it still a convention,  modification happend when inheritance is done, which still can be accessed. it is not a set rule like static languages. i maybe wrong. but this is as far as i can tell and not written in any docs or code level yet (to my knowledge)

Comment: What are the contents of `TreasureChestData.txt`?

Comment: @JonSG [link](https://replit.com/@MMujtabaH/GregariousScaredDesigner) you can check here

Comment: My previus test with fouble underscores was a bit different than this... and doing a bit of debigging I've noticed that actually @jasonharper is kinda right. The variables defined in `__init__` are stored differently (eg `__points` is `_treasureChest__points`).

Comment: I tested with single underscore and the values was returned this time.

Comment: Just because you can work around the name-mangling doesn't mean it's a mere convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root issue you see is that instance names that start with `__` are mangled (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables). That is what you are requesting by using that convention.

So to access them you would need to do something like:

```py
arrayTreasure[i]._treasureChest__question = question
```

in order to actual set the value.

For example:

```py
x = treasureChest("", bool(), 0)
print(x.getQuestion())

x.__question = "q"
print(x.getQuestion())

x._treasureChest__question = "q"
print(x.getQuestion())
```

However, I recommend you take a look at this code to see if it helps with importing your treasure data.

```py
class TreasureChest:
    def __init__(self,questionP, answerP, pointsP):
        self.__question = questionP
        self.__answer = answerP
        self.__points = pointsP

    def getQuestion(self):
        return self.__question
    
    def checkAnswer(self, answer):
        return self.__answer == answer

    def getPoints(self, attempt):
        if attempt == 1:
            return self.__points
        elif attempt == 2:
            return self.__points // 2
        elif attempt == 3 or attempt == 4:
            return self.__points // 4
        else:
            return 0

def get_treasure_chests(treasure_file_name):
    treasure_chests = []
    with open(treasure_file_name) as file_in:
        for question in file_in:
            treasure_chests.append(TreasureChest(
                question.strip(),
                file_in.readline().strip(),
                file_in.readline().strip()
            ))
    return treasure_chests

treasure_chests = get_treasure_chests("TreasureChestData.txt")

for treasure_chest in treasure_chests:
    print(treasure_chest.getQuestion())
```

That gives me back:

```
2*2
100/10
1000*4
125/25
3000+4000
```

Comment: I have changed the code now it works but there is another error [code](https://replit.com/@MMujtabaH/GregariousScaredDesigner#main.py). So basically I'm solving the question 3 of this pdf [A-Level CS](https://papers.gceguide.com/A%20Levels/Computer%20Science%20(for%20first%20examination%20in%202021)%20(9618)/2021/9618_s21_qp_41.pdf) you can get more information about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If this issue is 'solved", I recommend you open up a new one so that this issue stands alone should someone have this issue in the future.